Establish a short exact sequence $0\to Z_p\to Z_{p^2}\to Z_p\to 0$ does not split, every submodule of the projective module need not be projective.
Establish a short exact sequence $0\to Z_p\to Z_{p^2}\to Z_p\to 0$  does not split, every submodule of the projective module need not be projective.

p is prime nomber

Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3062900/calculating-operatornameext-mathbbz-2-mathbbz-2-over-mathbbz?rq=1 , try to adapt that answer to this one.

Thanks david but unfortunatly i have  not studied ext

Your question is not very clear. Here is an answer according to my understanding of the question.
If you are asking to find a sequence in the form of $0 \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0$, look at the sequence:
$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_2 \xrightarrow{i} \mathbb{Z}_{4} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$
with $i(z)=2z$ and $p(z)=z+im \ i$, which is indeed an exact sequence that does not split (notice $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \ncong \mathbb{Z}_4$).
If we consider $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_4$ as $\mathbb{Z}_4$-modules, this indeed shows that there exist submodules of projective modules that are not projective.
If you are asking to find a sequence in the form of $0 \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Z}_{p}^2 \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to 0$, if we consider $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a $R$-module for some suitable $R$ such $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^2$ is projective (as how your question is asking), then every $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ are projective, from being a direct summand of a projective.

God job thank u , yes i mean the first one of your ansower, but if you give me more detail about why it is not splits

If the sequence split, then $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$. However, all element in $\mathbb{Z}_2 ^2$ have order two. Is it the case for $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

i meant by Z sub (p^2) not (Zp)^2 nor (Z^2)sub p , and i want to prove it in general not for p = 2

A short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to0$ splits if and only if $B \cong A \oplus C$. Therefore, for your original sequence of $\mathbb{Z}p$ and $\mathbb{Z}{p^2}$, if the sequence split, then $\mathbb{Z}_p\oplus \mathbb{Z}p\cong \mathbb{Z}{p^2}$. I think It is quite trivial to see why this is not the case.

Ok , now which one is the projective module and wich one is not projective sub module in this sequence ?

And could u give me the theorem that says it is splits whenever  Z(p^2) = direct some of Zp s
